# Are there any drivers for Linux?

Tags: steam

So i have been trying to play some games on Ubuntu and its telling me I need to get a driver.

i cant find any. Is there anything for Linux on drivers? 
I have been searching and found nothing i tried GeForce and that doesn't work with Linux either 
Sorry i just got Ubuntu yesterday im new at this

Answer (score 2):

While Ubuntu comes with open source drivers (otherwise you wouldn't be able to use your hardware at all!), you might want official proprietary drivers for gaming.

Assuming you're using a Nvidia card (since you mentioned Geforce), see the instructions here!

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Installation

For AMD,

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to open the dash (the ubuntu button) and type "driver". It will open the additional drivers app. Use it to install the drivers.

You do not need to download drivers. The app download them from the repositories and install them